# Calculate correlation distribution of two columns in percentage

Tags: r, statistics, relationship, percentage

I'm working in a dataset with several data columns.

In this dataset  I have calculated the quantiles of 2 of two columns and I have converted the result of the quantiles into 2 new columns where each cells  shows a number of the quartile that belongs to.

[image: Image of quartiles columns]

Now I'd like to get the distributed relationship between this 2 columns.
I mean for example, when the result is 4 in  column 1 what is the relationship with the result of column 2?

For example:

**When result is 4 in column 1 = 30% of 1, 20% of 2 , 40% of 3, 10% of 4 in column 2**

And the same when the result is 1,2,3...

Maybe what I'm looking for has a name in statistics, but not sure what.

Anyone could help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- mtcars %>% 
   select(vs, gear) # the similar dataset 

data %>% 
    group_by(vs, gear) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(vs) %>% 
    mutate(perc = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.